# How to extract the longest apriori rule (association rule)

Tags: r, label, apriori

When use the following example:

```
library("arules")
data("Adult")
## Mine association rules.
rules <- apriori(Adult,parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9, target = "rules"))
> labels(rules)
```

You will see that following rules:

```
[5] "{sex=Male} => {capital-gain=None}"  
[20] "{race=White,sex=Male} => {capital-gain=None}"
[22] "{sex=Male,native-country=United-States} => {capital-gain=None}"
```

have the same `RHS` but are different in their `LHS`.
I would like to get the longest LHS rules only and to omit the short ones.
In the above mentioned example I would like to omit rule [5] since it is included in [20] and [22]. ({sex=Male} is included in [20] and [22]). I would like to stay with the longest rules only (in other examples the longest can have 3 or more components).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `is.subset` to get a logical matrix, and use that matrix to locate non-subsets:

```
subsets <- is.subset(rules, proper = TRUE)
subsets[lower.tri(subsets, diag=TRUE)] <- 0 # set lower triangle to 0
notsubsets <- rowSums(subsets) == 0L
labels(rules[notsubsets])


# [1] "{capital-gain=None,hours-per-week=Full-time} => {capital-loss=None}"                      
# [2] "{capital-loss=None,hours-per-week=Full-time} => {capital-gain=None}"                      
# [3] "{race=White,sex=Male} => {capital-gain=None}"                                             
# [4] "{race=White,sex=Male,native-country=United-States} => {capital-loss=None}"                
# [5] "{race=White,sex=Male,capital-loss=None} => {native-country=United-States}"                
# [6] "{sex=Male,capital-loss=None,native-country=United-States} => {race=White}"                
# [7] "{sex=Male,capital-gain=None,native-country=United-States} => {capital-loss=None}"         
# [8] "{workclass=Private,race=White,native-country=United-States} => {capital-loss=None}"       
# [9] "{workclass=Private,race=White,capital-loss=None} => {native-country=United-States}"       
#[10] "{workclass=Private,race=White,capital-gain=None} => {capital-loss=None}"                  
#[11] "{workclass=Private,race=White,capital-loss=None} => {capital-gain=None}"                  
#[12] "{workclass=Private,capital-gain=None,native-country=United-States} => {capital-loss=None}"
#[13] "{workclass=Private,capital-loss=None,native-country=United-States} => {capital-gain=None}"
#[14] "{race=White,capital-gain=None,native-country=United-States} => {capital-loss=None}"       
#[15] "{race=White,capital-loss=None,native-country=United-States} => {capital-gain=None}"       
#[16] "{race=White,capital-gain=None,capital-loss=None} => {native-country=United-States}"
```

`is.subset` counts the right-hand side when assessing whether it's a duplicate, and this is an issue with this approach.  As mentioned in a comment, the above approach missed the rule `{sex=Male,native-country=United-States} => {capital-gain=None}`:

```
labels(rules[c(22, 43)])
#[1] "{sex=Male,native-country=United-States} => {capital-gain=None}"                  
#[2] "{sex=Male,capital-gain=None,native-country=United-States} => {capital-loss=None}"
is.subset(rules[22], rules[43])
```

To get these cases, you can use `<= 1L` instead of `== 0L`, but then you'll get a false positive, too (`"{sex=Male,capital-gain=None} => {capital-loss=None}"` is a subset of `{sex=Male,capital-gain=None,native-country=United-States} => {capital-loss=None}`.

Comment: Thanks @Jota, but in your solution I can't find the rule {sex=Male,native-country=United-States} => {capital-gain=None}? This rule is not included in any other rules?

Comment: I get the following error: > subsets <- is.subset(rules, proper = TRUE)
Error in is.subset(rules, proper = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (proper = TRUE)

Comment: @Avi the reason it missed the rule you mentioned, `{sex=Male,native-country=United-States} => {capital-gain=None}` is explained in the edit.  Technically that is a subset of `{sex=Male,capital-gain=None,native-country=United-States} => {capital-loss=None}`.

Comment: Thanks, but why is it correct logically? Since they have different RHS?

Comment: @Avi The code works for me on Windows 10 in R 3.3.0 and R 3.2.15 with  arules_1.4-1.

Comment: I think that the reason for is.subset(rules[22], rules[43]) we get true stems from the fact that it relates to the LHS and not to the RHS using is.subset. Please be aware that I relate only to subsets that their RHS is equal. Does your code will work for this requirement?

Comment: @Avi see `labels(rules[c(3,4)])` where the LHS is the same but the RHS differs, and then see that `is.subset(rules[3], rules[4])` is `FALSE`.  Also, look in the Details section of `?is.subset`:  "For rules, the union of lhs and rhs is used a [sic] the set of items."